# Javascript method to sort by file name the same way Windows Explorer does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-explorer

Is there any JS function that alphanumeric sort a list of file name as string like the windows explorer does?

Comment: Can you please describe the "*way Windows Explorer uses*"? a) I don't have one at hand b) I don't want to reverse-engineer its rules c) I'm confident this has changed over time with Windows versions.

Comment: This function is `Array.sort`.

Comment: That's an interresting question, I'm facing the same problem right now : Win7 explorer has its own way to sort filesystem names like `"$RECYCLE.BIN"`, `".cache"`, `"_daa"` (note the underscore), `"cd[1]"`, etc. and there is no known simple comparer that can simply emulate that. What I have so far is to use `unicode` to `ascii` with `.toLowerCase()` converter, but even that can't properly compare underscore indexing. Well, I guess we have to create an entire unicode table/object lookup to make sure, but that's a nasty hit on performance - By the way, `Array.sort()` doesn't get anywhere near.

Comment: There's a simplier alternative : a.localeCompare(b) (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort), assuming we want to sort using local settings. But that doesn' solve the problem with underscores and $-like char either.